# Transfer USGS overlays to Google Earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth, earth-explorer

How to transfer aerial archives from USGS earth explorer onto GoogleEarth?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. [Register and create a account](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/register/)
2. Turn on layers that you are interested in downloading by clicking on the Data Sets button
3. Click the Results button to get the download icons per dataset, then download
4. You can create raster kml/kmz overlays either in ESRI ArcGIS ([Layer to KML tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004n000000)), GRASS (using [r.out.kml](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.out.kml) shell script), or use [OSSIM](http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki/kmlsuperoverlayplugin)
5. Once you have the kml/kmz layer you can right click and select Open With Google Earth to open it up in Google Earth

Hope that helps.